# Why simple logistic regression requires millions of iterations to converge?

Tags: machine-learning, julia, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

The problem is extremely simple, there are just 5 samples.

But the Gradient Descent converges extremely slow, like couple of millions of iterations.

Why, is there a mistake in my algorithm?

P.S. The Julia code below:

```
X = [
 1.0  34.6237  78.0247;
 1.0  30.2867  43.895;
 1.0  35.8474  72.9022;
 1.0  60.1826  86.3086;
 1.0  79.0327  75.3444
]

Y = [0 0 0 1 1]'

sigmoid(z) = 1 / (1 + e ^ -z)

# Cost function.
function costJ(Theta, X, Y)
    m = length(Y)
    H = map(z -> sigmoid(z), (Theta' * X')')    
    sum((-Y)'*log(H) - (1-Y)'*log(1 - H)) / m
end

# Gradient.
function gradient(Theta, X, Y)
    m = length(Y)
    H = map(z -> sigmoid(z), (Theta' * X')')    
    (((X'*H - X'*Y)') / m)'
end

# Gradient Descent.
function gradientDescent(X, Y, Theta, alpha, nIterations)    
    m = length(Y)
    jHistory = Array(Float64, nIterations)
    for i = 1:nIterations
        jHistory[i] = costJ(Theta, X, Y)        
        Theta = Theta - alpha * gradient(Theta, X, Y)        
    end
    Theta, jHistory
end

gradientDescent(X, Y, [0 0 0]', 0.0001, 1000)
```

Comment: how do you define "convergence"? Correct classification of all samples? Small L2 norm of gradient?

Comment: Hmm, that's a good question, I guess what I mean - finding the minimal value of cost function after a reasonable amount of iterations :). It seems like in this cause the reasonable amount should be hundreds or thousands, not millions.

Comment: In you gradient descent implementation there is no break. You should compare the reduction in cost function and if that's small enough than end the loop and return.

Comment: @niczky12 there's, it performs limited number of iterations `nIterations`

Comment: @Alexey Petrushin I thought you wanted to terminate the loop when it has reached the minimum. Sorry, I guess I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Check out this question about why small samples converge slower: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92321/when-optimizing-a-logistic-regression-model-sometimes-more-data-makes-things-go

Comment: try using `alpha = 0.01`

Answer (score 4):

I think @colinefang's comment may be the right diagnosis. Try plotting `jHistory` - does it always decrease?

Another thing you can do is add a [simple linesearch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking_line_search) on each iteration to make sure the cost always decreases, something like:

```
function linesearch(g, X, Y, Theta; alpha=1.0)
    init_cost = costJ(Theta, X, Y)

    while costJ(Theta - alpha*g, X, Y) > init_cost
        alpha = alpha / 2.0 # or divide by some other constant >1
    end

    return alpha
end
```

Then modify the gradient descent function slightly to search over alpha on each iteration:

```
for i = 1:nIterations
    g = gradient(Theta, X, Y)
    alpha = linesearch(g,X,Y,Theta)
    Theta = Theta - alpha * g
end
```

There are various performance enhancements you can make to the above code. I just wanted to show you the flavor.